# What are the formal names of operands and results for basic operations?

Tags: arithmetic

I'm trying to mentally summarize the names of the operands for basic operations. I've got this so far:

- Addition: Augend + Addend = Sum.
- Subtraction: Minuend - Subtrahend = Difference.
- Multiplication: Multiplicand × Multiplier = Product. Generally, operands are called factors.
- Division: Dividend ÷ Divisor = Quotient.
- Modulation: Dividend % Divisor = Remainder.
- Exponentiation: Base ^ Exponent = ___.
- Finding roots: Degree √ Radicand = Root.

My questions:

- I've heard *addend* used generally for addition operands. Is that correct formal usage?
- Do subtraction and division lack general names for their operands because they are not commutative? Or am I just ignorant of them?
- Is the base the same as a mantissa?
- Is there a formal name for the result of exponentiation?
- Is there a formal name for the operation of finding the nth root?
- Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Not a full answer, but with regard to the 2nd question: I've heard "[nominator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159081/numerator-vs-denominator-vs-nominator)" has been used before to describe a generic operand of division, but its usage is rare.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- You will often see the terms in a general sum referred to as "addends" or "summands".
- Your suggestion regarding subtraction/division as compared to addition/mulipilication is as good as any. The roles of the operands are not interchangeable, so a single description isn't really appropriate.
- I've usually seen *mantissa* referring to the multiplier of a power in certain expressions. Specifically, in scientific notation. For example, in the expression $2.345\times10^8$, the mantissa would be $2.345$. It has other usage in connection with logarithms, but you can look that up.
- One sometimes refers to "powers". For example, a polynomial in one variable $x$ can be described as a sum of constant multiples of nonnegative powers of $x$. Technically, the "power" is the exponent, but it is also used on occasion to refer to the entire expression (base and exponent).
- Nothing comes immediately to mind regarding extracting roots.

I will comment that many of these names contain a wealth of Latin. If you happen to know Latin, you will understand their meaning more deeply. For example, "minuend" comes from a form meaning "about to be lessened" and "subtrahend" come from a form meaning "about to be taken away". In general, "-nd" will carry the meaning "about to be ---ed".

Comment: "*Nothing comes immediately to mind regarding extracting roots*", that's *degree* and *radicand* (radic = root, e.g. in radix or in eradicate). I'm curious about the use of *term* and *factor* respectively for a sum and a product when the position is not important. Are they less common? In French they are the only words we use and *addend* form is only found in *addendum*, the words added after the fact to a document.

Comment: I know I'm like 10 years late but I've heard "radication" used as a way (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#History)

Answer (score 46):

Found this table on Wikipedia. It has all the formal names for those operations plus logarithm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Calculation_results

### Addition

${\left.{\begin{matrix}{\text{summand}}+{\text{summand}}\\{\text{addend (broad sense)}}+{\text{addend (broad sense)}}\\{\text{augend}}+{\text{addend (strict sense)}}\end{matrix}}\right\}}=sum$

### Subtraction

${\text{minuend}}-{\text{subtrahend}}=difference$

### Multiplication

$\left.{\begin{matrix}{\text{factor}}\times {\text{factor}}\\{\text{multiplier}}\times {\text{multiplicand}}\end{matrix}}\right\}=product$

### Division

${\left.{\begin{matrix}{\frac {{\text{dividend}}}{{\text{divisor}}}}\\{\text{ }}\\{\frac {{\text{numerator}}}{{\text{denominator}}}}\end{matrix}}\right\}}={{\begin{matrix}fraction\\quotient\\ratio\end{matrix}}}$

### Modulo

${\text{dividend}}{\bmod {\text{divisor}}}=remainder$

### Exponentiation

${\text{base}}^{\text{exponent}}=power$

### nth root

${\sqrt[{\text{degree}}]{{\text{radicand}}}}=root$

### Logarithm

$\log _{\text{base}}({\text{antilogarithm}})=logarithm$

Comment: Can you add more details? Once you have earned reputation, you can post this as a comment.

Comment: I agree. I tried, but copying an HTML table while retaining markup (like those big multiline braces) is hard. I also tried to attach a picture, but I don't have enough reputation for that.

Comment: Isn't "quotient" only for euclidean division (when there's also a remainder)? Or does it refer to real division (or whatever it's called) as well? If I'm talking specifically about real/rational division should I avoid using "quotient" to avoid confusion and use "ratio" instead?