# what are the formal names of operands of unary operations?

Tags: arithmetic, convention

In case of binary operations, operands have formal names.

Taking addition for example:
$$a + b$$
We can formally call $a$ the augend and $b$ the addend. Names for operands are available in individual Wikipedia articles, for addition it is here: [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition#Notation_and_terminology), as well as all-in-one in this page: [Calculation results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Calculation_results). Some of them are available as well in this question: [What are the formal names of operands and results for basic operations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975541/what-are-the-formal-names-of-operands-and-results-for-basic-operations)

But what I just cannot find anywhere is... Formal details regarding unary operations. My question is, do operands of unary operations have formal names? I suspect the answer is yes, but what are they?

Taking a list from Wikipedia [Unary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation#C_family_of_languages) for C programming language for example:

- Increment: `++x`, `x++`
- Decrement: `−−x`, `x−−`
- Address: `&x`
- Indirection: `*x`
- Positive: `+x`
- Negative: `−x`
- Ones' complement: `~x`
- Logical negation: `!x`
- Sizeof: `sizeof x`, `sizeof(type-name)`
- Cast: `(type-name) cast-expression`

Disregarding the programming context, and considering only the operations met also in mathematics, does anyone know the names for operands in these? In case of $+1$, is $1$ the addend? In case of $-5$, is $5$ the subtrahend? What about incrementing, is the operand called... incremend?

Comment: Just say "operand". Why complicate things?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Agreed. Still, OP would like to know the technical names.

Comment: My motivation is simply curiosity. Maybe someone invented or heard about some concrete names for those... I just want to know :)

Comment: My suggestion: study Latin. That's where the names you mention come from anyway. On the other hand, they're just fancy-sounding names which just mean exactly what they are, and aren't more accurate than their English descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest neo-Latinisms as these terms do not exist historically.

"Addend" and "subtrahend" are definitely wrong, since these refer to quantities which are to be added or subtracted; I might suggest "signand" in both cases instead (for the unary sign operators).

One might similarly refer to "increscend" or "decrescend" for the argument of the ++ and -- operators. In any event, they are certainly "operands" in general.