# Operand names for generic operation

Tags: arithmetic

For [binary arithmetic operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) (addition, subtractions, multiplication, etc.) the form is an operator and two operands.  Each arithmetic operator has its down names for the operands ([this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975541/what-are-the-formal-names-of-operands-and-results-for-basic-operations)).  For example, with addition there augend and addend; subtraction has minuend and subtrahend.

My question is, are there operand names for the generic operator form?  That is, if you have `a operator b` where `operator` is some binary operation, are there names other than "first operand" and "second operand"?

If not, would something like "unoperand" and "duoperand" be correct (not exactly sure how to apply Latin prefixes)?

Comment: I don't know of any such name, but I recommend not trying to invent such a term or using one that is relatively obscure, and instead just say "first coordinate", "second coordinate", or something else that would be generally understood from context (although you still might want to define the terms). A good way to lose a lot of potential readers is to sprinkle idiosyncratic terms throughout your exposition. That said, you should just look at any of the standard texts on universal algebra and see what's done there.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you and I'll see what I can find on universal algebra.  I would up-vote your comment, but I don't yet have that ability on this part of StackExchange.